# scanf() taking more inputs than expected

Tags: arrays, c, string

I was attempting a problem to check symmetry in logos (link : https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/arrays/multi-dimensional/practice-problems/algorithm/roy-and-symmetric-logos-1/description/). This is the function accepting input of the array called logo[][]:

```
void take_Logo(int logo[N_Max][N_Max], int N)   //N is number of rows and columns
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char in[80];
    for(i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {          
        for(j = 0; j<N; j++)
        {
            //gets(in);                                       //error in input here
            scanf("%s", in);
            logo[i][j] = in[j] - '0';
        }
    }
}
```

The trouble is that when I run the code, for N = 2, it takes 4 inputs:

```
2
01
01
01
01
```

How do I correct it?

I am entering the 01's as a binary string.

Here is the complete code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N_Max 32
int check_Symm(int logo[N_Max][N_Max], int N);
void take_Logo(int logo[N_Max][N_Max], int N);

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0, T, N, logo[N_Max][N_Max];
    scanf("%d", &T);
    i = T;
    while(i > 0)
    {
        --i;
        scanf("%d", &N);
        take_Logo(logo,N);
        //check_Symm(logo, N) == 0 ? printf("NO\n") : printf("YES\n");
        for(int k = 0; k<N; k++)
        {
            for(int l = 0; l<N; l++)
            {
                printf("%d ", logo[k][l]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}

void take_Logo(int logo[N_Max][N_Max], int N)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char in[80];
    for(i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {          
        for(j = 0; j<N; j++)
        {
            //gets(in);                                       //error in input here
            scanf("%s", in);
            logo[i][j] = in[j] - '0';
        }
    }
}

int check_Symm(int logo[N_Max][N_Max], int N)
{
    int test = 1;
    if(N % 2 == 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < N/2; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<N; j++)
            {
                if(logo[i][j] == logo[N-1-i][j])
                    continue;
                else
                {
                    test = 0;
                    return test;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < N/2; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<N; j++)
            {
                if(logo[j][i] == logo[j][N-1-i])
                    continue;
                else
                {
                    test = 0;
                    return test;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < N/2; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<N; j++)
            {
                if(logo[i][j] == logo[N-1-i][j])
                    continue;
                else
                {
                    test = 0;
                    return test;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < N/2; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<N; j++)
            {
                if(logo[j][i] == logo[j][N-1-i])
                    continue;
                else
                {
                    test = 0;
                    return test;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i < N/2 ; i++)
        {
            if(logo[N/2][i] == logo[N/2][N-i-1])
                continue;
            else
            {
                test = 0;
                return test;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i < N/2 ; i++)
        {
            if(logo[i][N/2] == logo[N-i-1][N/2])
                continue;
            else
            {
                test = 0;
                return test;
            }
        }
    }
    return test;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",...)` is no better than `gets`.  See one of several hundred thousand references on the internet for why you should not use `gets`.

Comment: But you haven't shown enough.  Where is the code that is reading `N`?  Please post a complete example.

Comment: What William meant with a "complete" example, I assume they he meant a [mre], which means that you should not post a big blob. Make a minimal example that compiles.

Comment: @user3121023 Thanks. It seems to solve the problem

Comment: @klutt Sorry, didn't know. But the issue is solved. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: You need to limit the length `%s` will accept, like `%79s`. You also need to check the return value from scanf. Read the scanf documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The trouble is that when I run the code, for N = 2, it takes 4 inputs:

This is expected for `N == 2`:

```
// Do loop twice
for(i = 0; i<N; i++) {          
    // Do loop twice
    for(j = 0; j<N; j++) {
        // Read 2 * 2 times
        scanf("%s", in);
        logo[i][j] = in[j] - '0';
    }
}
```